# exclude a div from the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #0e1538;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="spaceholder" width="804" height="604"></canvas>

</div>

<div class="MenüCenter">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

  <section id="GameOver">
    <h1 class="title">GAME OVER!</h1>
    <h3 id="RestartBTN">Restart?</h3>
  </section>

  <section id="StartMenu">
    <h1 class="titlestart">Welcome to space adventure</h1>
    <h3 id="PlayBTN">Play</h3>
  </section>

  <section id="Pause">
    <h1 class="titelPause">Pause</h1>
    <h3 id="ResumeBTN">Resume</h3>
  </section>
</div>

<div class="ScoreClass">
  <h2 id="TimeScoar"></h2>
</div>
```

This is what I have for my body. Now I want to align the div class ScoreClass to the right, how is that possible? Can I exclude the div ScoreClass?

I would appreciate, if you could give me an answer.
Jonathan

Comment: means one div to right? float:right?

Comment: You should use Grid or make two containers in your body, place that div in one and the rest of elements in another, then use flex columns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the position to the right in your CSS.

```css
.ScoreClass {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%; /*sets element all the way to the right (adjust percentage to your need)*/
}
```

Comment: this will cause a nasty collision (hiding elements layer-wise). As you move the element completely out of flow and obscuring other elements.

Comment: How? collision to what? The OP asked to align the div to the right and the element is a div so its not a 3d object if you are refering collision as in bounding box intersect. Is there any thing im not noticing in the question that would caue the collision. @tacoshy

Comment: z-index can be set to negative if hiding other object is an issue. Also if author wants to have score on top right corner all the time then `position: fixed` could be used.

Comment: the element will be moved out of flow and set to the right side no matter if there already elements at. it will collide with those elements and display absolute to the nearest relative parent: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/LYjmzQr

Comment: Thx for the help i found a way that it works :D

Comment: yeah i mean i always use this method when working on my THREE JS projects never had collisions problem or anything. NP